# Twitter object is always null I have taken example from twitter4j

Tags: twitter4j

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {

```
    TwitterFactory twitterFac = new TwitterFactory();
    Twitter twitter = twitterFac.getInstance();
    twitter.setOAuthConsumer("key", "secret");
    request.getSession().setAttribute("twitter", twitter);
    try
    {
        RequestToken requestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken("http://local.your-domain.com:8080/sign-in-with-twitter/callback");
        request.getSession().setAttribute("requestToken", requestToken);
        System.out.println(requestToken.getAuthenticationURL());
        response.sendRedirect(requestToken.getAuthenticationURL());
    } catch (TwitterException e)
    {
        throw new ServletException(e);
    }

}
```

}

****Then the twitter page redirects to a page of my application (CallbackServlet). All this is performed correctly.****

Then the CallbackServlet has the following doGet method:

public class CallbackServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1657390011452788111L;

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    Twitter twitter = (Twitter) request.getSession().getAttribute("twitter");
    RequestToken requestToken = (RequestToken) request.getSession().getAttribute("oauth_token");
    String verifier = request.getParameter("oauth_verifier");
    try {
        twitter.getOAuthAccessToken(requestToken, verifier);
        request.getSession().removeAttribute("requestToken");
    } catch (TwitterException e) {
        throw new ServletException(e);
    }
    response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/");
}
```

}

=============================
The CallbackServlet tries to get the twitter and requestToken saved in the LoginServlet (using the method getSession().getAttribute()). This is where the problem is: the twitter object is always null!

plz sort it out